# How to get all users from the discord server?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

After migration from discord-api v.1.0 to v.1.2.3 I had problems with getting all members from the server.

In version 1.0 I did it like this:

```
for member in ctx.message.server.members:
    print(member.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rewrite it would look like this: (made a small command)

```py
    @bot.command()
    async def server_users(ctx):
        for member in ctx.guild.members:
            print(member)
```

Hope it helps :D